# Logged in user image show on blade (laravel)

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I want to show logged in user image:

```
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $image_name = $request->hidden_image;
        $image = $request->file('image');

        if ($image != '') {
            $request->validate([
                'name'      =>  'required',
                'email'     =>  'required',
                'phone'     =>  'required',
                'image'     =>  'image|max:2048'
            ]);
            
            $image_name = rand() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $image->move(public_path('images'), $image_name);
        } else {
            $request->validate([
                'name'      =>  'required',
                'email'     =>  'required',
                'phone'     =>  'required'
            ]);
        }

        $form_data = array(
            'name'      =>   $request->name,
            'email'     =>   $request->email,
            'phone'     =>   $request->phone,
            'image'     =>   $image_name
        );

        User::whereId($id)->update($form_data);
        return redirect()->route('manage-user');
    }
```

This is my update function where I ask user to add image and store image in public folder and the images are store in public folder but I want to show image of logged in user on a sidebar.

```
        <div class="user-profile w-50 text-dark">
            <img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/images/{{ $data->image }}" class="rounded-circle img-thumbnail mb-3" width="200" height="200" alt="">
            <h4>Name: {{ $data -> name }}</h4>
            <h4>Email: {{ $data -> email }}</h4>
            <h4>Phone: {{ $data -> phone }}</h4>
        </div>
```

This is my blade. Thanks in advance

Comment: what `<img src=` is being generated ? can you put that as well .?

Comment: If your path is correct , then it will work `<img src="/images/{{ $data->image }}" class="rounded-circle img-thumbnail mb-3" width="200" height="200" alt="">` just remove `{{ URL::to('/') }}` it gives you extra slash before the src path

Comment: `<img src="{{ url('public/images/'.auth()->user()->image) }}"` you need to try as this.

Comment: it did not work! I want to show the logged in user image in the sidebar

Comment: Like this i show the logged in user name: {{ Auth::user()->name }}

Comment: For loggedin user, pass as `auth()->user()->image`

Comment: No need to repeat your question. We understand what you want to do. Please answer the comments instead, like showing the generated HTML.

Comment: To display images, you should be using `assets()`. Be sure you have linked your storage folders.

Comment: `Auth::user()->image` or `auth()->user()->image` will work , if user has a `image` field on the `users` table, we exactly don't know what the `$data` contains here, you can do like this src="/images/{{ Auth::user()->image }}"

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys, my problem is solved DilipHirapara and sta your answers are correct. Thanks again